# Build Action is not support in this configuration in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I am using netbeans 7.4 , I created a HTML5 project , when i click the build tool , it will prompt a message "Action is not support in this configuration" , may  I know what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no Build action for HTML5 project unless it is Cordova project, otherwise there is nothing to build. To make "plain" HTML 5 project "Cordova" project, you can set its target browser to some Cordova target (android device, iOS device etc) using for instance the browser picker in main menu or (I think) you can open project properties, select Cordova category and click on the button to create Cordova resources. Then build action will be available and will create apk/app file.

**Edit for NetBeans 8.0.1**: If you have Gruntfile.js in project root folder, you can go to project properties in NetBeans, select Grunt category and map Grunt tasks to build/clean

Comment: Wow! This is still true in Netbeans 8.0.1